# Touchpad driver for Dell Inspirion?

Tags: 15.04

I have recently purchased the new Dell Inspirion 3000 that comes pre-installed with Ubuntu. It came with Ubuntu 14.04 and some Dell bloatware, so I decided to do a clean install with Ubuntu 15.04. Unfortunately, now the touchpad doesn't work and I'm forced to use a USB mouse. Where could I possibly obtain a driver for the touchpad?

Here is the output from the `xinput` command:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL06AB:00 06CB:78F1                      id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. It's working now. Thanks.